How can one generate the list of all files a prettier invocation will consider?
I have a step in my CI pipeline in which I want to process exactly the same list of files that our standard command-line invocation of prettier will parse/check. But because of things like our .prettierignore file, the parsers/plugins active, and so on (this is a multi-language project), it seems as though this list is pretty difficult to reconstruct exactly, except by some use of prettier itself. (It does, after all, have a noticeably large amount of code in prettier/src/cli/expand-patterns.js for the purpose of generating this file list.)
I seem to have found a hackish method: Thanks to this template I made a micro-plugin "prettier-list.js" (quoted in full below) that is unhappy with every file. I can then run something like
npx prettier --parser listing-parser --plugin tools/prettier-list.js --check .
and scrape out the file names from the parade of warnings it produces. My question is, is there a better way? We'd ideally prefer one that doesn't involve maintaining a dummy plugin and parsing warning messages. I didn't notice anything helpful in the prettier API, but perhaps I am missing something?
Code of prettier-list.js:
const PARSER_NAME = 'listing-parser';
const AST_FORMAT_NAME = 'listing-dummy-ast';

function parse(_text, _options) { return {node: 'dummy'} }
function locStart(_node) { return 0 }
function locEnd(_node) { return 1 }
function print(path, options, print) { return '' }

export const languages = [
  {name: 'JustListTheFiles', parsers: [PARSER_NAME]},
];

export const parsers = {
  [PARSER_NAME]: {parse, astFormat: AST_FORMAT_NAME, locStart, locEnd},
};

export const printers = {
  [AST_FORMAT_NAME]: {print},
};

export const options = {};
export const defaultOptions = {};


With your plugin, but without --check, try --list-different.  It should be easier to parse.

Indeed, that brings the hackishness down a notch. Thanks.

I think this would be a useful feature for multiple purposes, especially troubleshooting .prettierignore.  If it doesn't exist, you may want to file a feature request.  It could be called --list-all.
